# How to add ALL (*) route that has the same prefix as base?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, multilingual

I'm building a multilingual website and having a problem with React Router.

Every path starts with `/:lang` and continues with the path of the relevant page:

Like this:

```
"/:lang/profile"
"/:lang/stores"
"/:lang/products"
"/:lang"
```

I want to redirect to 404 page when path doesn't match to any of the paths of available pages.
Since all of the paths start with same thing, I need to use `exact` attribute.
But since `exact` check all routes before matching one, the Route with the `"*"` path at the end always matches and page always redirects to 404 even with the existing paths. I tried `"/:lang/*"` too, but nothing different happened. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: which version react router you using

Comment: Which version of `react-router-dom` and do you need to capture the `lang` as a route match param? If using a `Switch` then you should check the order of the paths since path specificity and order matters for matching. You shouldn't need the `exact` prop at all for 99.9% of use cases. Can you actually show us your code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may be rendering your routes into a router without the benefit of using the `Switch`. While `Router` will ***inclusively*** match and render all matching routes (*thus sometimes requiring the `exact` prop*), the `Switch` ***exclusively*** matches and renders the first matched route. Also note that in a `Switch` that path order and specificity matter! Order the routes from ***more*** specific paths to ***less*** specific paths.

Example:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/:lang/profile" component={Profile} />
  <Route path="/:lang/stores" component={Stories} />
  <Route path="/:lang/products" component={Products} />
  <Route path="/:lang" component={Lang} />
  <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Here the more specific paths will try to be matched first, then the less specific "/:lang" path, and if that doesn't match, the 404 component is rendered as a "catch-all" for anything that wasn't matched previously above it.

Comment: In my situation, I used Route components inside another Route component which is inside a Switch component. In other words, I have Switch at only the first step. May I put another Switch component inside the Route component of the previous one ?

Comment: @noiseymur Yes, you can use any number of `Switch` components, even nested. Though, you may need to account for any nesting by ***not*** specifying the `exact` prop on any "root" routes rendering these nested `Switch` and `Route` components.

Answer (score 1):

you need to wrap your all path, `Route component={NotFound}` will get rendered if not found any

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/lang" component={Lang}/>
      <Route exact path="/lang/profile" component={Profile}/>
      <Route component={NotFound}/>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

old way was, with `Redirect` and then map that url to, this uses redirect feature,

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/404" component={NotFound} />
    <Redirect to="/404" />
</Switch>
```

if you using react-router v6, Redirect is removed, but still you do Navigate with *, `import {Navigate } from "react-router-dom";`

```
import {Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/404" element={<div>Wrong 404 path/div>} />
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/404" />} />
  </Routes>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Is NotFound a custom component ?